# OpenCV where is tracking.hpp

Tags: c++, opencv, tld

I want to use an OpenCV's implementation of the TLD tracker. Internet says that I have to include this file: `opencv2/tracking.hpp` (e.g. see https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/tracking/samples/tracker.cpp).

But there is no such a file.

Well, what must I do to use TrackerTLD in my C++ project?

(OpenCV 3.0.0 beta for Windows, installed from the .exe package from opencv.org)

Comment: This file is located at opencv\build\include\opencv2\video directory.

Comment: Floyd, this file exists, but there is no TrackerTLD class here. Also I have found that this one is implemented in the _contrib repo_ (http://answers.opencv.org/question/51561/opencv30-tldtracker/). Can you explain please how to use it?

Comment: You have to download contrib repo from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib and build it. You can find all instructions in the link above.

Answer (score 9):

As Floyd mentioned, to use TrackerTLD, you need to download [OpenCV contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) repo. Instruction is in the link, so explaining it shouldn't be necessary.
However in my opinion using TrackerTLD from OpenCV repo is bad option - i've tested it (about a week or 2 ago) and it was terribly slow. If you are thinking about real time image processing, consider using other implementation of TLD or some other tracker. Right now i'm using [this implementation](https://github.com/gnebehay/OpenTLD) and it's working really well. Note that tracking an object is quite a time consuming task so to perform a real time tracking i have to downscale every frame from 640x480 to 320x240 (Propably it would work well (and definitely faster) in even lower resolution). On the [web page](http://www.gnebehay.com/tld/) of author of this implementation you may find some informations about TLD algorithm (and implementation) and another tracker created by this author - CMT(Consensus-based Matching and Tracking of Keypoints). Unfortunetely i haven't test it yet so i can't tell anything about it.