# Error while setting up openCV in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to run a project using openCV in VS2015, I have added the libraries and linked them but still got an error about the video tracker, however I didn't have an error about the cor utility. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need the video contrib download see  [OpenCV where is tracking.hpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619037/opencv-where-is-tracking-hpp)

This contains extra algorithms not part of the main distribution

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I am not sure what shall I do after downloading it. Shall I add the tracking folder to my opencv folder ? could you please advice me?

Comment: Did you build it from source? If you downloaded a pre-built library you probably just unpack into the same top level directory

Comment: it gives me two errors:
- class "cv::Tracker" has no member "create" 
- a reference of type "cv::Rect2d &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "cv::Rect"

not sure why?